# Visualize Two Measures coming from Different tables into a single chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

to learn PowerBI I sought to create a Stock Market App that'll help me monitor my Portfolio.

PBIX File - [Here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/ZztblJOP#link)

With some great help from David and Sam! I'm making some progress but the thing is currently I've two tables one with Benchmark data - `NiftyHistoricData` and a table with all the stock price quotes - `StockHistoricData`.

[image: Stock and Benchmark line chart]

I want to show both of them in the same chart but the thing is my stocks chart is shown individually by using a legend to separate all the stocks.

[image]

I want the benchmark data (The light blue one) to show in the stock chart just like any other stock. Is there a way to do the same? Also, it'll be great if I can Slice the Benchmark line chart to disappear away if I deselect it from the slicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current line chart is a bit limited in this regard. As soon as you add a legend, you're constrained to just the values that exist in that legend. The way to solve this is not to use a legend and instead create a separate measure for each value in GrowthHistoric (e.g. TCS_GrowthHistoric) and then add a final measure for NiftyHistoricGrowth.

Comment: Thanks, Davide! I wouldn't want to do that because my stock list will keep on growing as per my objectives for this project. But Thanks for Answering the question I'll think of some other way to Compare the Same. This pretty is much what wanted to hear as I couldn't find ant help Googling it out.

Comment: You could try Vega Lite line chart in Deneb which is a lot more flexible. https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, David! I'll look into Vega Lite. Appreciate the help.